# Spring boot call back URL not bringing token on giving state and code

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a spring boot Oauth2 project trying to incorporate it with Angular.
Project code is at https://github.com/gpdotsingh/idea/tree/master.

- Branch is master
- Backend is spring boot that is in server folder
- Front end is in the idea folder that is angular

Facing problem while calling below callback URL from angular it is not giving access token when I am trying to call it from front end that is localhost:4200,
giving response as http://localhost:8086/login;jsessionid=B66BE0E6982DD95E8E36BA32D2A1655C?error

But when I am calling the same code from localhost:8086 it redirects me to the login page from spring security and further it give the proper response.

call back url is : http://localhost:8086/login/oauth2/code/cognito1?code='+code+'&state='+state
Code for my project is :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
        private final ObjectMapper mapper;
    
        @Autowired
        private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    
        public WebConfigurer(ObjectMapper mapper) {
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }
    
     
    
        //Add cors , as spring security is getting used
        //hence the cors need to be declared here as well else with application.properties it won't work**
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .cors()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/oauth2/**", "/login**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    //.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    //.and()
                    .oauth2Login()
                    .successHandler(this::successHandler)
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/",true)
    
            ;
    
            http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    
    
        }
    
        private void successHandler(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
            OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken =
                    (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
            System.out.println("oauthToken:::" + oauthToken);
            response.getWriter().write(
                    mapper.writeValueAsString(Collections.singletonMap("token", authentication.getAuthorities()))
            );
        }
    
    
        @Bean
        public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
            return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
                @Override
                public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                    registry.addMapping("/**")
                            .allowedOrigins("*")
                            .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

The class for my client config is

```
  @Configuration
  public class OAuth2LoginConfig {
  
      @Bean
      public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
          return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(this.clientRegistration());
      }
  
      private ClientRegistration[] clientRegistration() {
          ClientRegistration [] crArray = new ClientRegistration[2];
  
          ClientRegistration cr1 =
                  ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("cognito2")
                          .clientName("app-client1")
                          .clientId("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
                          .clientSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
                          .scope(new String[]{"openid"})
                          .authorizationUri("https://xxxxxxx.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize")
                          .tokenUri("https://xxxxxxx.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token")
                          .userInfoUri("https://xxxxxxx.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/userInfo")
                          .jwkSetUri("https://cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/us-east-xxxxxxx/.well-known/jwks.json")
                          .clientName("app-client")
                          .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                          .redirectUri("http://localhost:4200/callback")
                          .build();
  
          ClientRegistration cr2 =
                  ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("cognito1")
                          .clientName("app-client2")
                          .clientId("xxxxxxxxx")
                          .clientSecret("xxxxxxxxxxx")
                          .scope(new String[]{"openid"})
                          .authorizationUri("https://xxxxxxx.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize")
                          .tokenUri("https://xxxxxx.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token")
                          .userInfoUri("https://xxxxxxxx.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/userInfo")
                          .jwkSetUri("https://cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/us-east-2_72ZHiqEHa/.well-known/jwks.json")
                          .clientName("app-client2")
                          .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                          .redirectUri("http://localhost:4200/callback")
                          .build();
  
          crArray[0] = cr1;
          crArray[1] = cr2;
          return crArray;
      }
  
  }
```

And code for angular callback component is

```
  
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
   import { SecurityServiceService } from 'src/app/services/security-service.service';
   
   @Component({
     selector: 'app-callback',
     templateUrl: './callback.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./callback.component.css']
   })
   export class CallbackComponent implements OnInit {
   
     constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute
       , private router : Router
       , private securityService: SecurityServiceService) { }
   
     ngOnInit(): void {
       this.route.queryParams.subscribe(p=>{
         console.log("code and state "+p);
         this.securityService.fetchToken(p.code,p.state) // Not able to call fetch data
         .subscribe(data=>{
           console.log("tokes "+data);
           this.securityService.updateToken(data.token);
           this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
         })
       })
     }
   
   }
```

Services code is

````
   
   import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
   
   @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
   })
   export class SecurityServiceService {
   
     private url ="https://xxxxxxxx.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxx&scope=openid&state=xxxxxxxxx%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/callback&nonce=NJJQy8vKDEVbZ533VQWanAneNojgg4aTeKlh6_E1x1Y";
     private tokenKey ='token';
     constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
   
     login()
     {
       window.open(this.url,'_self');
     }
   
     getToken()
     {
       return localStorage.getItem(this.tokenKey);
     }
   
     fetchToken(code:string,state:string): Observable<any>
     {
       state = encodeURIComponent(state);
       code = encodeURIComponent(code);
       console.log("State is "+ state+ "   code "+code);
   
       return this.http.get('http://localhost:8086/login/oauth2/code/cognito1?code='+code+'&state='+state);
     }
   
     updateToken(token: string)
     {
       localStorage.setItem(this.tokenKey,token);
     }
     
     isLoggedIn(): boolean
     {
       const token = this.getToken();
       return token!=null;
     }
   
   }
   ```


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIvIK.png
````

Comment: 404 means not found, so your Login link does not seem to match your  Spring configuration. I do not really have a clue about about Spring OAuth Config, but  your matchers do not match your link... .antMatchers("/oauth2/", "/login**") vs http://localhost:8086/login/oauth2/code/cognito1?code='+code+'&state='+state

Comment: Its going to backend but from backend its not able to bring the token.
Spring boot provides functionality for calling callback URL by itself and in angular it is then not goinh inside -- 'this.securityService.fetchToken(p.code,p.state) '' this code

Comment: Sorry to say but it is not giving 404 error sorry for my mistake